# String encoding in javascript UTF-16 or UTF-8

Tags: javascript, string

While reading [charAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) in MDN, I've found that strings in javascript sequence of UTF-16?

So to verify my understanding, I've tried the following script in NodeJS

```
Buffer.from("€").length // gives 3
```

How can this be 3 bytes? As far as I know, this should be either 2 or 4 bytes, How can UTF-16 string give 3 bytes?

I've looked at different questions here in StackOverflow but didn't find an explanation for this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when [creating a `Buffer.from` a string](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding), it needs an encoding, and if you don't specify one, it defaults to UTF-8.

You seem to be looking for either

```
Buffer.from("€", "utf16le").length
```

or just

```
"€".length * 2
```